# Does NatTable need a manual refresh after repaintCell?

Tags: java, nattable

I have the following code snippet.

```
    int index = getEventList().indexOf(myObj);
    SelectionLayer selectionLayer = getGlazedListsGridLayer()
       .getBodyLayerStack().getSelectionLayer();        
    getNatTable().repaintCell(0,selectionLayer.getRowIndexByPosition(index));
```

When I run the code shown above, the affected cells only get repainted after I click on the table displayed in the GUI.  If I comment out that code and use `getNatTable().refresh();` it repaints without me having to first click on the table.

Is there a way to have a cell repainted without having to click on the table displayed in the GUI?  I would hate to have to call refresh() for a large table where this code may be executed many times.

Comment: Why do you want to call repaintCell() manually anyway?

Comment: I have an image on that cell that may change due to some external factor

Comment: To be more specific, I register a callback with external code. Through the callback I get the object (called myObj) and I use myObj to determine the cell which needs to change.  When I call repaintCell(), it re-runs the necessary IConfigLabelAccumulator code to determine the correct image to display. The IConfigLabelAccumulator code calls an external service with myObj to determine which image to draw. The data held in the table does not change, since the image is determined from something outside of myObj. In other words, myObj does not have an internal value which changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to perform some additional step in order to trigger the repainting. The issue in your code is the usage of wrong index values. You have a grid so column 0 is the row header from the NatTable perspective. I suppose you want to redraw the first column of the body, which is index 1 from the NatTable point of view. Also the row index is incorrect, as you calculate the index in the SelectionLayer but actually need the index in the table, which is at minimum +1 if you only have a column header row.

Actually your code should work by adding 1 on the index if you have one row header column and one column header row in the grid.

```
getNatTable().repaintCell(1, selectionLayer.getRowIndexByPosition(index) + 1);
```

Comment: I notice that when I sort columns the repaint may or may not happen as expected. There is no rhyme or reason and I have to click on a row to have the proper icons displayed.  Is there another call I can make to refresh a particular cell?

Comment: please read about the index-position transformation. On NatTable you operate on positions which is actually what you currently see. If you transform to index the cell you want to repaint is probably not visible, as the index represents the actual data position in the underlying list. There is a chapter about that in the Getting Started Tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html

Comment: So I'm supposed to repaint the cell based on the DataLayer then?  I read the article but it makes no sense to me as to how to solve the issue with the given code sample

Comment: Your problem is that you get the index of the base EventList. Which is different to what is shown when sorted. Probably your issue is fixed if you ask the SortedList for the index.

Comment: I tried the following, but it doesn't repaint until after it's clicked on:
'getNatTable().repaintCell(myCol, getGlazedListsGridLayer().getBodyDataProvider().indexOfRowObject(myObj));'

Comment: Then you don't have the correct positions. As I explained above 0 is the position of the headers in a grid. So you need the +1

Comment: If the manual index-position transformation is too complicated you could also try to fire a CellVisualUpdateEvent from the bodyDataLayer upwards. bodyDataLayer.fireLayerEvent(bodyDataLayer, 0, index)